# How to edit dashboard search posts button texts for my CPT?

Tags: filters, search, dashboard

I am new to WordPress Development. Can I change texts of filter search box button ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When registering the post type you should set the `search_items` label:

```
register_post_type(
    'question',
    array(
        // etc.
        'labels' => array(
            // etc.
            'search_items' => 'Search Questions',
        ),
    )
);
```

You can see the full list of labels that you can set [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_labels/).

Comment: thanks, it worked